# Minimal C++ STL Vector Implementation Problems

Tags: c++, stl, vector, g++, segmentation-fault

I have a technical problem and it's really confusing me. I apologise in advance because I may not be giving the relevant details; I don't yet why it's going wrong and it would be excessive to include all the code I'm working with.

I'm working with a large program that uses the C++ STL. I'm moving this code to a very sensitive environment without a standard clib nor STL implementaton; it will redefine malloc/free/new/delete etc... For that, I need to replace the std:: parts with my own simplified implementations. I've started with std::vector. Right now it's running in the standard ecosystem so it's the GNU libc and STL. The only thing that's changed is this vector class.

When I execute the program with the replaced class, it segfaults. I've put this through GDB and found that the program will request an object from the vector using the subscript operator. When the object reference is returned, a method is invoked and the program segfaults. It seems it can't find this method and ends up in main_arena() in GDB. The type of the object is an inherited class.

I'm really not sure at all what the problem is here. I would love to provide additional details, but I'm not sure what more I can give. I can only assume something is wrong with my vector implementation because nothing else in the program has been changed. Maybe there's something obvious that I'm doing wrong here that I'm not seeing at all.

I'm using: g++ (GCC) 4.4.5 20110214 (Red Hat 4.4.5-6)

I'd really appreciate any feedback/advice!

```
#ifndef _MYSTL_VECTOR_H_
#define _MYSTL_VECTOR_H_

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef unsigned int uint;

namespace mystl
{
    /******************
      VECTOR
    ********************/


    template <typename T>
    class vector 
    {

        private:

            uint _size;
            uint _reserved;
            T *storage;

            void init_vector(uint reserve)
            {
                if (reserve == 0)
                {
                    _reserved = 0;
                    return;
                }

                storage = (T*)malloc(sizeof(T)*reserve);
                assert(storage);

                _reserved = reserve;
            }

        public:
            vector()
            {
                    // std::cerr << "default constructor " << this << std::endl;
                    storage = NULL;
                    _size = 0;
                    _reserved = 0;
            }

            vector(const vector<T> &other)
            {
                // std::cerr << "copy constructor " << this << std::endl;

                storage = NULL;
                _size = 0;
                _reserved = 0;


                init_vector(other.size());
                _size = other.size();

                for (uint i=0; i<other.size(); i++)
                {
                    storage[i] = T(other[i]);
                }
            }

            vector(uint init_num, const T& init_value)
            {
                    // std::cerr << "special constructor1 " << this << std::endl;

                        storage = NULL;
                        _size = 0;
                        _reserved = 0;

                      init_vector(init_num);

                      for (size_t i=0; i<init_num; i++)
                      {
                          push_back(init_value);
                      }
            }

            vector(uint init_num)
            {
                    // std::cerr << "special constructor2 " << this << std::endl;

                        storage = NULL;
                        _size = 0;
                        _reserved = 0;

                      init_vector(init_num);
            }

            void reserve(uint new_size) 
            {   
                if (new_size > _reserved) 
                {

                    storage = (T*)realloc(storage, sizeof(T)*new_size);
                    assert(storage);

                    _reserved = new_size;
                }
            }

            void push_back(const T &item) 
            {
                if (_size >= _reserved) 
                {
                    if (_reserved == 0) _reserved=1;
                    reserve(_reserved*2);
                }

                storage[_size] = T(item);
                _size++;
            }

            uint size() const
            {
                return _size;
            }

            ~vector()
            {
                if (_reserved)
                {
                    free(storage);
                    storage = NULL;
                    _reserved = 0;
                    _size = 0;
                }
            }

            // this is for read only
            const T& operator[] (unsigned i) const
            {
                // do bounds check...
                if (i >= _size || i < 0)
                {
                    assert(false);
                }
                return storage[i];
            }


            T& operator[] (unsigned i)
            {
                // do bounds check...
                if (i >= _size || i < 0)
                {
                    assert(false);
                }
                return storage[i];
            }

            // overload = operator
            const vector<T>& operator= (const vector<T>& x)
            {
                // check for self
                if (this != &x)
                {   
                    _reserved = 0;
                    _size = 0;
                    storage = NULL;

                    init_vector( x.size() );

                    for(uint i=0; i<x.size(); i++)
                    {
                        storage[i] = T(x[i]);
                    }

                    _size = x.size();
                }

                return *this;
            }

            uint begin() const
            {
                return 0;
            }

            void insert(uint pos, const T& value)
            {
                push_back(value);
                if (size() == 1)
                {
                          return;
                }
                for (size_t i=size()-2; i>=pos&& i>=0 ; i--)
                {
                    storage[i+1] = storage[i];
                }
                storage[pos] = value;
            }

            void erase(uint erase_index)
            {
                if (erase_index >= _size) 
                {
                    return;
                }
                //scoot everyone down by one
                for (uint i=erase_index; i<_size; i++)
                {
                    storage[i] = storage[i+1];
                }
                _size--;
            }


            void erase(uint start, uint end)
            {

                if (start > end)
                {
                    assert(false);
                }

                if (end > _size)
                    end = _size;

                for (uint i=start; i<end; i++)
                {
                    erase(start);
                }

                assert(false);
            }

            void clear()
            {
                erase(0,_size);
            }

        bool empty() const
        {
            return _size == 0;
        }

    }; //class vector
}


#endif // _MYSTL_VECTOR_H_
```

Comment: Can you give us a simple `main()` that replicates the segfault?

Comment: This looks dodge `if (i >= _size || i < 0)`, how can `unsigned i` be less than 0?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't replicate the fault with minimised code. I suppose something is happening between the time I create the objects, store them in the vector, and access them again. I'll play around some more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wow!

1. Your assignment operator also leaks memory.
2. Becuause you are using malloc/release the constructor to your type T will will not be called and thus you can not use your vector for anything except the most trivial of objects.

#### Edit:

I am bit bored this morning: Try this

```
#include <stdlib.h> // For NULL
#include <new>      // Because you need placement new

// Because you are avoiding std::
// An implementation of swap
template<typename T>
void swap(T& lhs,T& rhs)
{
    T   tmp = lhs;
    lhs = rhs;
    rhs = tmp;
}


template <typename T>
class vector
{
    private:
        unsigned int dataSize;
        unsigned int reserved;
        T*           data;

    public:
        ~vector()
        {
            for(unsigned int loop = 0; loop < dataSize; ++loop)
            {
                // Because we use placement new we must explicitly destroy all members.
                data[loop].~T();
            }
            free(data);
        }
        vector()
            : dataSize(0)
            , reserved(10)
            , data(NULL)
        {
            reserve(reserved);
        }

        vector(const vector<T> &other)
            : dataSize(0)
            , reserved(other.dataSize)
            , data(NULL)
        {
            reserve(reserved);
            dataSize = reserved;
            for(unsigned int loop;loop < dataSize;++loop)
            {
                // Because we are using malloc/free
                // We need to use placement new to add items to the data
                // This way they are constructed in place
                new (&data[loop]) T(other.data[loop]);
            }
        }

        vector(unsigned int init_num)
            : dataSize(0)
            , reserved(init_num)
            , data(NULL)
        {
            reserve(reserved);
            dataSize = reserved;
            for(unsigned int loop;loop < dataSize;++loop)
            {
                // See above
                new (&data[loop]) T();
            }
        }

        const vector<T>& operator= (vector<T> x)
        {
            // use copy and swap idiom.
            // Note the pass by value to initiate the copy
            swap(dataSize, x.dataSize);
            swap(reserved, x.rserved);
            swap(data,     x.data);

            return *this;
        }

        void reserve(unsigned int new_size)
        {
            if (new_size < reserved)
            {    return;
            }

            T*  newData = (T*)malloc(sizeof(T) * new_size);
            if (!newData)
            {    throw int(2);
            }

            for(unsigned int loop = 0; loop < dataSize; ++loop)
            {
                // Use placement new to copy the data
                new (&newData[loop]) T(data[loop]);
            }
            swap(data, newData);
            reserved    = new_size;

            for(unsigned int loop = 0; loop < dataSize; ++loop)
            {
                // Call the destructor on old data before freeing the container.
                // Remember we just did a swap.
                newData[loop].~T();
            }
            free(newData);
        }

        void push_back(const T &item)
        {
            if (dataSize == reserved)
            {
                reserve(reserved * 2);
            }
            // Place the item in the container
            new (&data[dataSize++]) T(item);
        }

        unsigned int  size() const  {return dataSize;}
        bool          empty() const {return dataSize == 0;}

        // Operator[] should NOT check the value of i
        // Add a method called at() that does check i
        const T& operator[] (unsigned i) const      {return data[i];}
        T&       operator[] (unsigned i)            {return data[i];}

        void insert(unsigned int pos, const T& value)
        {
            if (pos >= dataSize)         { throw int(1);}

            if (dataSize == reserved)
            {
                    reserve(reserved * 2);
            }
            // Move the last item (which needs to be constructed correctly)
            if (dataSize != 0)
            {
                new (&data[dataSize])  T(data[dataSize-1]);
            }
            for(unsigned int loop = dataSize - 1; loop > pos; --loop)
            {
                data[loop]  = data[loop-1];
            }
            ++dataSize;

            // All items have been moved up.
            // Put value in its place
            data[pos]   = value;
        }

        void clear()                                        { erase(0, dataSize);}
        void erase(unsigned int erase_index)                { erase(erase_index,erase_index+1);}
        void erase(unsigned int start, unsigned int end)    /* end NOT inclusive so => [start, end) */
        {
            if (end > dataSize)
            {   end     = dataSize;
            }
            if (start > end)
            {   start   = end;
            }
            unsigned int dst    = start;
            unsigned int src    = end;
            for(;(src < dataSize) && (dst < end);++dst, ++src)
            {
                // Move Elements down;
                data[dst] = data[src];
            }
            unsigned int count = start - end;
            for(;count != 0; --count)
            {
                // Remove old Elements
                --dataSize;
                // Remember we need to manually call the destructor
                data[dataSize].~T();
            }
        }
        unsigned int begin() const  {return 0;}


}; //class vector
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback. Can you elaborate on the erase problem?

Comment: @Bob, have a very careful look at the loop conditions, esp. the end condition checks.

Comment: @Bob: and the assert. And the complexity of erase. Currently it is O(n^2)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something. Are you saying the erase is poorly implemented or semantically wrong? I agree with the former but I'm not seeing the latter. It probably looks strange that the second erase calls the first erase with erase(start) and start is a constant variable. This makes sense when the semantics of the first erase are considered.

Comment: Thanks for the code. It's segfaulting in the reserve function but it's a better guide to work from. I'm curious as to why you implemented operator= using a swap? We don't want to modify the RHS, right?

Comment: @Bob: No I want to make a copy of the RHS so I can then use the swap. It is the standard way of implementing the assignment operator. Please look up `Copy and Swap Idiom`

Comment: Hi, thanks! Actually, it was because the size/reserve was being set in the initialisation lists. I replaced it with 0 and all was well. As for the operator=, I only notice now that we're passing by value and not by reference. It makes more sense now. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @LokiAstari: Thanks for your help. There were a couple of things I had to change to make it work (in the constructors and the erase) but it's great now. Thanks for your help, I appreciate it. What's curious is that I had been trying to modify my own with in place News but it segfaulted as always.

Comment: @Bob In the construcors you never initialize the `loop` variable.  There's your segfault.  Turn your warnings up higher.

Answer (score 2):

With your current memory handling, this vector would only work with plain old data types.

To handle all types, it must ensure that objects

- are actually created (malloc doesn't do that),
- destroyed (free doesn't do that),
- and you can't reallocate memory with realloc, because complex objects are not guaranteed to remain valid if they are byte-wise copied to another location.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the answer can be found in your question: "When the object reference is returned, a method is invoked and the program segfaults. It seems it can't find this method and ends up in main_arena() in GDB. The type of the object is an inherited class."

You probably store base class instance T in the vector, but make push_back for the instance of the class inherited from T. In push_back {storage[_size] = T(item);} you cast (actually make copy constructor T:T(const T&)) item to T (this probably named 'type cut'), then get reference to T and invoke a method of the class inherited from T using virtual table of T where the method is not defined yet/abstract. Am I right?
To make it properly work you should put T* in the vector or shared_ptr/unique_ptr depending on the ownership terms you apply to vector elements.
Generally in vector you can store only POD (Plain Old Data) types.

Comment: Hopefully this is still useful three and a half years later :)

Comment: Many of sequence container users are not aware of the C++ standard and "strange" errors multiply.

Comment: As addition to my comment above:
C++ ISO standard text: "23.2.3 Sequence containers
A sequence container orginizes a finite set of objects, all of the same type, ..."

The type of the object is defined at construction time as the most derived object constructor call. Even if it is casted then to the base class it still has its own type. But when type cut happens the type of the resulted object is changed to the base type and type becomes the same as the base class it is casted.